# More elegant realization of packed ASCII algorithm in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I need to unpack the string of packed ASCII characters. The algorithm is following:

1. Get 3 packed ASCII bytes, put them into 4 ASCII bytes. (6 + 6 + 6 + 6 bits in 3 bytes to 4 bytes)
2. For each byte, set bit 6 as complement to bit 5.
3. For each byte reset bit 7 to zero.
4. Repeat for next 3 packed bytes.

I'm new to Ruby, may be there is more correct and elegant way to solve this task, rather my code:

```
while i < pstr.length 
    parr = [pstr[0] & 0x3F, pstr[0]>>6 | ((pstr[1] << 2 ) & 0x3F),
            pstr[1]>>4 | ((pstr[2] << 4 ) & 0x3F),
            pstr[2]>>2]
    parr.collect! { |a| a | (~(a << 1) & 0x20) }        
    parr.collect! { |a| a & 0x7F }

    puts parr

    i += 3
end
```

Update1: Thx for correction of collect.

Comment: Just to clarify: Your code works as intended (e.g. passes tests), but you would like help with Ruby idioms or short-cuts? Could you add some test inputs and verified outputs to the question, it would help.

Comment: Have you looked at `#unpack`? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-unpack

Comment: @UriAgassi As i read in docs, Ruby doesn't support packed ASCII code in pack/unpack.

Comment: @NeilSlater Code works on samples that i have, but ofc have bugs, just want to clarify that I understand Ruby construction correctly and there is no way to solve this problem in more compact way using Ruby features. Thanks for correction of collect.

Comment: Could you provide a couple of the test samples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though ruby's [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) don't directly support ASCII pack and unpack, they do support Base64 by way of `pack('m')` and `unpack('m')`. This can help with the bit-shifting involved with translating to and from 3 bytes that hold 8 relevant bits each, and 4 bytes that hold 6 each.

Here's a starting implementation of `pack` and `unpack` which is a bit more ruby-esque. `pack` operates on strings which are an exact multiple of 4, dropping any remainder. Conversely `unpack` expands every 3 characters to 4.

```
B64 = ('A'..'Z').to_a+('a'..'z').to_a+('0'..'9').to_a+%w(+ /) # Base64 alphabet
H64 = Hash[B64.zip(0..63)] # Hash character to index

# Translates every 4 characters to 3, drops any remainder
def pack( ascii )
    ascii.bytes.map { |b| B64[b&(b&0x40==0?0x3f:0x1f)] }.join.unpack('m')[0]
end

# Translates every 3 characters to 4
def unpack( bstr )
    [bstr].pack('m').chomp.split('').map do |c|
       ( (H64[c]|0x40) & (H64[c]&0x20==0?0x5f:0x3f) ).chr
    end.join
end
```

Example usage:

```
ascii_packed = pack('Hello World!')
puts ascii_packed.length # => 9
puts unpack( ascii_packed ) # => "HELLO WORLD!"
```

For those unfamiliar with ASCII-pack, it is a "lossy" compression. ASCII characters `x` outside the range `0x20 <= x < 0x60` are translated to a character within that range. This is why lower case letters get capitalized when packed/unpacked.